# Adding and counting cells containing formulas

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to do two things.  Using Excel 2010.
I want to add the value of a range of cells whose value is derived from this formula:  `=IF(M8=1,"1",IF(M8=2,"0",IF(M8=3,"N/A")))`.  I've tried `SUMIF` formulas to only add the values in the range if `=1`, doesn't work.  I've used a formula adding each cell individually (M8+M9+M10 etc), but if the value = `N/A` is doesn't work.

Separately, I want to count the number of cells with a value of 1 and 0 but not N/A.  I'm stumped nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use quotes around the numbers, try this version

`=IF(M8=1,1,IF(M8=2,0,IF(M8=3,"N/A")))`

Now you should be able to sum the results using SUM function because the results are numeric rather than text (and N/A will be ignored by SUM function)

...and to count 1s with COUNTIF, assuming range is N2:N100 use COUNTIF like

`=COUNTIF(N2:N100,1)`

do the same with zeroes

[of course counting the 1s is the same as summing the range because 1 is the only non-zero number that your formula produces]